# ionic cli vs ionic cli2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-cli

I have not seen/found anything about the differences between ionic cli v1 and ionic cli v2, and I had a couple of questions related to this, if anyone could let me know it would be super helpful.

I have an ionic v1 project, but when I run any ionic commands, it tells me my cli (1.7.16) is out of date, and that I should update to ionic cli v2.

So my questions are:

1. Since I have an ionic v1 project, should I be updating to cli 2, should the cli 2 support both ionic v1 and v2 projects?
2. Related to this, it looks like cli 2 kind of works with my ionic 1 project, however, it keeps on telling me that I should change ionic.project to ionic.config.json, so I was wondering, is this recommendation actually a difference between ionic v1 and ionic v2 projects, and that since I have ionic v1, I should keep it as ionic.project, or should I really switch it to ionic.config.json.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the cli v2 supports ionic 1 projects, so you should have no issues there. The change to ionic.config.json does apply to both v1 and v2 projects.

Comment: I have now updated to cli 2, however, it seems that an ionic.project file still gets generated on my build process with a name and app_id. Any ideas why that is happening?

Comment: Do you mean the ionic.config.json file? If so, that stores info about the app that is used by the `ionic upload` command and Ionic Cloud platform.